# SL4A, PythonForAndroid and Android 7.0 Nougat

Tags: python, sl4a

I have got information for SL4A first from https://github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android

- SL4A : sl4a-r6.1.1-arm-debug.apk
- PY4A : PythonForAndroid-debug.apk

There are installable APKs for sl4a - r6.1.1 version and python interpreter - r26 version. They are working basically on **Android Nougat** but some functions are not working or looks little unstable.

Good to me to see that Google is developing SL4A again.

So, I tried to install new sl4a 7.0 from **Android Nougat** version. I got source codes from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sl4a/ and made sl4a.apk

**Problem**

> sl4a 7.0 doesn't work with current PythonForAndroid interpreter - r26. When I execute SL4A
>   on device, crash is happening.

**Here is logcat**

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
AndroidRuntime: Process: com.googlecode.android_scripting, PID: 22750
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary /data/user/0/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python does not exist!
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.SingleThreadExecutor.afterExecute(SingleThreadExecutor.java:32)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1141)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary /data/user/0/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python does not exist!
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.interpreter.Interpreter.setBinary(Interpreter.java:118)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.interpreter.Interpreter.buildFromMaps(Interpreter.java:73)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.interpreter.InterpreterConfiguration$InterpreterListener.buildInterpreter(InterpreterConfiguration.java:173)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.interpreter.InterpreterConfiguration$InterpreterListener.addInterpreter(InterpreterConfiguration.java:119)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.interpreter.InterpreterConfiguration$InterpreterListener.-wrap0(InterpreterConfiguration.java)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.android_scripting.interpreter.InterpreterConfiguration$InterpreterListener$2.run(InterpreterConfiguration.java:101)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
```

Actually, python is located in exact directory. This problem looks like permission issue. 
Anyone help me to solve this issue ?